# Format data from database if data contains a tab-sign

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a website in which users input text into a textarea.
This text is saved into a database table and is later shown in a div element

Sometimes a user pastes data from Excel into the textarea, I wish to retain the table layout from Excel after I pull it from the database and present it on my webpage

Example:

```
test    cat1    cat2
data1   1   2
data2   3   5
data3   6   5
```

Is it possible (probably with js) that on loading the page a code checks if a tab-sign is in the data? And if yes, format that data as a html table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY As below. Just giving you idea.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var text = document.getElementByID("txtareaID").value;

var isTab = text.indexOf("\t");

if(isTab != '-1')
{
var tableCell = text.split("\t");
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tableCell.length ; i++) {

            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerText = tableCell[i];
            tr.appendChild(td);

    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
}
tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for tab characters using `\t` to see if the character exists in the string. Something like this

```
var text = "test cat1 cat2 data1 1 2 data2 3 5 data3 6 5";
var tabsFound = text.indexOf("\t");
```

Comment: that helps me in the right direction. How do i create a html table if a \t is found?

Comment: I think this post might be useful. But instead of commas you have tabs.
 [Create html table from comma separated strings javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612667/create-html-table-from-comma-separated-strings-javascript)